# Setting the value with condition inside for each applying to all items instead of just 1

Tags: java, for-loop, playframework, ebean

I have really strange issue over here, the problem that I make iteration over list inside object inside list, and there is a condition for it, the problem is that second iteration has condition to set value but its applying to all items even if condition is false.

I have the following classes:

EventFeedKey (used as key for hashmap):

```
public class EventFeedKey {
    private final int eventId;
    private final int triggerId;

    public EventFeedKey(int eventId, int triggerId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
        this.triggerId = triggerId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof EventFeedKey)) {
            return false;
        }

        EventFeedKey otherKey = (EventFeedKey) object;
        return this.eventId == otherKey.eventId && this.triggerId == otherKey.triggerId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = 17; // any prime number
        result = 31 * result + Integer.valueOf(this.eventId).hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + Integer.valueOf(this.triggerId).hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    private EventType type;

// Setters and Getters
}
```

EventType:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_types")
public class EventType {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "eventType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference  
    private List<EventTypeTrigger> triggers = new ArrayList<>();

// Setters and Getters
}
```

EventTypeTrigger:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_type_triggers")
public class EventTypeTrigger  {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Transient
    private int count;

// Setters and Getters
}
```

And the following must return the list and the triggers filled with count value from `triggersFeed` .

```
    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
    if (eventList != null) {
        HashMap<EventFeedKey, Integer> triggersFeed = getTriggersWithCounts();
        eventList.stream().forEach(event -> {
            event.getType().getTriggers().stream().forEach(eventTypeTrigger -> {
                EventFeedKey key = new EventFeedKey(event.getId(), eventTypeTrigger.getId());
                eventTypeTrigger.setCount(triggersFeed.get(key) != null ? (Integer) triggersFeed.get(key) : 0);
            });
        });
        return eventList;
    }
```

And inside `getTriggersWithCounts()` :

```
public HashMap<EventFeedKey, Integer> getTriggersWithCounts() {
    HashMap<EventFeedKey, Integer> eventTriggers = new HashMap<>();
    // event id : 1, trigger id 7
    eventTriggers.put(new EventFeedKey(1,7), 5);
    return eventTriggers;
}
```

Lets says I have the following data :

for `eventList` :

```
[  
   {  "id":1, "title":"Team A vs Team X", 
      "type":{  
         "id":3,
         "title":"Baseball",
         "triggers":[  
            {  
               "id":7,
               "title":"Base Reached",
               "count":0
            },
            {  
               "id":8,
               "title":"Out",
               "count":0
            }
         ]
      }
   },
      {  
      "id":2, "title":"Team A vs Team C",
      "type":{  
         "id":3,
         "title":"Baseball",
         "triggers":[  
            {  
               "id":7,
               "title":"Base Reached",
               "count":0
            },
            {  
               "id":8,
               "title":"Out",
               "count":0
            }
         ]
      }
   },
]
```

The result (which is wrong) that I get from the method is :

```
[  
   {  "id":1, "title":"Team A vs Team X", 
      "type":{  
         "id":3,
         "title":"Baseball",
         "triggers":[  
            {  
               "id":7,
               "title":"Base Reached",
               "count":5
            },
            {  
               "id":8,
               "title":"Out",
               "count":0
            }
         ]
      }
   },
      {  
      "id":2, "title":"Team A vs Team C",
      "type":{  
         "id":3,
         "title":"Baseball",
         "triggers":[  
            {  
               "id":7,
               "title":"Base Reached",
               "count":5
            },
            {  
               "id":8,
               "title":"Out",
               "count":0
            }
         ]
      }
   },
]
```

And most annoying, if I added this :

```
if (triggersFeed.get(key) != null) {
    System.out.print(triggersFeed.get(key).toString());
}
```

It will print out only one result!

So Issue is : Why the event with `id:2` modified?

**Edit**:
I think the issue now related to Ebean : http://ebean-orm.github.io/ that I use inside Playframework.

Comment: How are you constructing your data? My feeling is that you have pointer to same EventType in both Event instances and when you update it from one event, it is same object which is present in other Event

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski These are entities that I get from database, and I have another list but in 1 level (not nested loop) have no problem like this. I was think about pointer, but in debug I don't see this.

Comment: I executed the sample you provided (constructed each input Event manually) and the output was exactly as expected (only the EventTypeTrigger id=7 for event id=1 is modified).  Almost assuredly you either have a problem where the same EventTypeTrigger objects are used in both events.

Comment: well, the issue in debug the objects looks so different, and even make no sense, there are entities and i'm using play framework with ebean

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski thanks, I got the idea, the hint you said made me to look after ebean framework that was the issue for this, the ebean was reference same entity instance sense they are with same "id", i'm not sure is it a bug or not but this was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks for @ArturBiesiadowski for the hint, the issue simply was from Ebean that was reference the entity instance since they have same `@Id` , so even that I was set value for 1 entity but when I get entity I get the same instance, even that I was not persist that entity, and they are different before I retrieve the list, but seems Ebean get the modified one with getter when I get the list back after I did my modification.

The solution was simply using another objects (Like DTO), I'm already have them before, but I was modify the list and then return the DTOs, what I have made I converted the list to DTOs then modified the list, and this made it works.

I'm using http://mapstruct.org/ to map between Entities and DTO, my DTO classes, are the same of Entity classes but without annotations.

EventDTO:

```
public class EventDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private EventTypeDTO type;

// Setters and Getters
}
```

EventTypeDTO:

```
public class EventTypeDTO {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private List<EventTypeTriggerDTO> triggers = new ArrayList<>();

// Setters and Getters
}
```

EventTypeTriggerDTO:

```
public class EventTypeTriggerDTO  {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private int count;

// Setters and Getters
}
```

And the code now is:

```
    List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();

    if (eventList != null) {
        List<EventDTO> eventDTOList = new ArrayList<>(EventMapper.INSTANCE.map(eventList));
        HashMap<EventFeedKey, Integer> triggersFeed = getTriggersWithCounts();
        eventList.stream().forEach(event -> {
            event.getType().getTriggers().stream().forEach(eventTypeTrigger -> {
                EventFeedKey key = new EventFeedKey(event.getId(), eventTypeTrigger.getId());
                eventTypeTrigger.setCount(triggersFeed.get(key) != null ? (Integer) triggersFeed.get(key) : 0);
            });
        });
        return eventDTOList;
    }
```

Sure you need to go to MapStruct documentation for Mappers, but if you don't want use Mapper of mapstruct the idea is just to map entity classes to DTO classes, use any Mapper you want, but what I'm sure about is that the MapStruct working well in this case.